# prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_NF(\frac{1}{\pi n})=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(\frac{t}{\pi})}{2t}dt$

Tags: calculus, fourier-series, riemann-sum

I've been trying to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_NF(\frac{1}{\pi n})=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(\frac{t}{\pi})}{2t}dt$

this was in a quiz 2 years ago.
I assume it somehow is related to Darboux sums, the problem I face is that I can't understand how a Fourier series of a constant isn't a constant.
When I take the limit of the expression in the SNF I get a zero.
Does anyone understand?

Comment: What is $S_NF$?

Comment: this:
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/ee8a9d351e797851579997548fed5f4cd69cf96e
whereas p=2pi

Comment: You should show $S_NF$ directly.  The link wasn't much help.